# thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to any of [port , 10000] PyHive

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyhive

I am having issues with my python code. When I run my code. It says

```
[2022-02-11 09:58:28,740] ERROR in app: Exception on /process_file [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_cors/decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "apicall-backup.py", line 1746, in process_file
    create_tmp_table(res['file_path'], table_name,res['file_delimiter'],filename)
  File "apicall-backup.py", line 187, in create_tmp_table
    conn = hive.Connection(host=str(config.hive_host), port=int(config.hive_port), username=str(config.hive_username))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 243, in __init__
    self._transport.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 74, in open
    self._trans.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 146, in open
    raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.NOT_OPEN, message=msg)
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to any of [('port', 10000)]
10.2.2.200 - - [11/Feb/2022 09:58:28] "POST /process_file HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have looked around for a solution to find whether hive is running or not? I found it to be running. I used beeline to access hive. applied some commands. the commands were responded properly. here is a screenshot

[image: Screenshot 01]

At a place I read that, this error may occur due to Zookeeper service failure. I tried that too and the results are as follows.

[image]

Any help in this regard!

Comment: You'll need to show more of your Python code. What are the values in `config`? Do those match the values in the _full_ `beeline` command? Does your Hiveserver actually listen on port 10000?